# 'dict' object has no attribute 'all_aircraft'

Tags: python, django

I have a list of posts that the user is able to favorite and save to their to their account. However, I keep getting the error message above. Does anybody have any idea as to where the issue lies?

**views.py:**

```
def AircraftFavourite(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Aircraft, id=id)
    queryset = Aircraft.objects.all()
    context = {'all_aircraft' : queryset}
    try:
        selected_aircraft = context.all_aircraft.get(pk=request.POST['context'])
    except(KeyError, Aircraft.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request,'aircraft.html', {
            "aircraft" : instance,
            "error_message" : "You did not select a valid aircraft",
        })
    else:
        selected_aircraft.is_favorite = True
        selected_aircraft.save()
        return render(request,'aircraft.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

  url(r'^detail/(?P<id>\d+)/$', AircraftDetail, name='AircraftDetail'),
  url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/favourite/$', AircraftFavourite, name='AircraftFavourite'),]
```

**aircraft.html**

```
{% block content %}
  {% for a in all_aircraft %}
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th><a href="{% url 'AircraftDetail' id=a.id  %}"> {{ a.title }}</a>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <form action="{% url 'AircraftFavourite' id=a.id  %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" id="aircraft{{ forloop.counter }}" name ="aircraft" value="{{ a.id  }}">
            <label for="aircraft{{ forloop.counter }}"
            {% if aircraft.is_favourite %}
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b9b13Rd.png" />
            {% endif %}
            <input type="submit" value="Favourite"><br>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>


  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately flight mode is not enabled for python dictionaries __yet__

Comment: `foo.bar` and `foo['bar']` are not equivalent in Python. You can't access the `'all_aircraft'` key of the `context` dict as `context.all_aircraft`.

Comment: It's a valid question because in templates they __are__ equivalent, so that might cause confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In django templates attribute access and item access are equivalent:

#### template.html

```
#rendered with context = dict(a=dict(something=5), b=SomeObject))
<body>
  {{ a.something }} vs {{ b.something }}
</body>
```

Both will work and django figures out whether to access the attribute or get the item.

However in Python, the attribute access with the `.` is **not** equivalent to item access with the brackets `[ ]`.

Your script should be changed to reflect this:

```
    try:
        selected_aircraft = context['all_aircraft'].get(pk=request.POST['context'])
```

Or ideally just access the queryset directly, so the code better reflects what you're doing:

```
    try:
        selected_aircraft = queryset.get(pk=request.POST['context'])
```

Comment: Yes, this works, however it doesn't return back to the lists page. How would I do that because I thought I already implemented it in with the return render?

Comment: I have very limited understanding of your code and there is a lot to be improved/ done differently, I don't even know where to start. Please consider accepting this question if it solved your problem, and ask a new, more specific question about your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

`selected_aircraft = get_object_or_404(Aircraft, id=request.POST['context'])`